# Facebook php sdk showing error

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm getting this error some times

Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1039

This is how i'm displaying the user name.Is any thing missing here?

```
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
  $userInfo = $facebook->api("/$user_id");
  $accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_sdfsdfsdfsd_access_token'];
  echo  $userInfo['name']."<br />";
  $uid = $userInfo['id'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to include some more code just to make sure you do in fact have a valid session for the user.

Try something like this:

```
$user_id=null;
try{
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
}catch(Exception $e){
  //could help if you log this error
}

if($user_id){
  try{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,gender,locale'); //I just ask for specific fields
  }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    //could help if you log this error
    $user_id = null;
  }
}

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => ''));

if (!$user_id) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'. $loginUrl .'";</script>';
  exit;
}

//FYI: How I get the access_token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: P:This is giving me a blank page.